# C# Unity Script is there a way to speed up Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts that talk to each other basically my spawn script grabs a boolean from a simple script. The boolean is set to true at the end of the if statement to show the light is on. Now I have a collider script that Instantiates 2 prefabs. But it's very slow. This game is supposed to be fast since it's being demoed to a lot of people is there a way to speed this up.

```
private bool Once = true;
public Transform Spawnpoint1;
public Transform Spawnpoint2;

public GameObject Prefab1;
public GameObject Prefab2;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (Once == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("It's true");
        if (LightOnOff.torchLit == true)
        {
            Debug.Log(" It's Lit");
            Instantiate(Prefab1, Spawnpoint1.position, Spawnpoint1.rotation);

            Instantiate(Prefab2, Spawnpoint2.position, Spawnpoint2.rotation);

            Once = false;
        }

    }
}
```

If you are wondering the simple script looks like this

```
public static bool torchLit;

public void lightOn()
{
    this.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
    torchLit = true;
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is slow, and how did you identify that it was slow?

Comment: The line of code isn't slow the objects that spawn in are taking forever so right after    `Debug.Log(" It's Lit");`

Comment: That command show in my console so I know the if statement worked but It takes quite a while to do so.

Comment: Instantiation and destruction of gameobject is known to require a lot of resources. It is easily accessable information online. take a look at https://answers.unity.com/questions/196413/gameobject-pool-to-avoid-performance-issues-in-ins.html

Comment: I had no idea I am very new to Unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**Object Pooling**](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling). It is common practise for fast `Instantiate` objects.

How it works?

1. Instantiate objects on scene loading.
2. Set objects `acitve` to `false`and `position` to 0, 0, 0.
3. When you need object just set `active` to `true` and set `position` to desired `position`.
4. When  object is no longer needed, instead of destroying, just again set `acitve` to `false`and `position` to 0, 0, 0.

I really recommend you to watch that tutorial. Maybe do deeper research about it or... just use free `Asset` from `Asset Store`.